# Example with regards to the Point Class (JAVA)

Tags: java, point

```
Point[] p = new Point[3];
for (int i=1; i<3; i++) {
p[i].setLocation( p[i-1].getX()+1, p[i-1].getY()+2 );
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(p));
```

With regards to this question, will the output be:

- [java.awt.Point[x=0,y=0], java.awt.Point[x=1,y=2],
  java.awt.Point[x=2,y=4]]

OR

- Error

Comment: Why don't you just try?

Answer (score 0):

It would throw a NullPointerException because you are never instantiating any point instance in the array.